# Storing dynamic lengths of time on the database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay, so I need something like this:

```
time_span = "1.month" 
date = DateTime.now 
date = date + send("#{time_span}")
```

where time_span is actually stored on the database, but that doesn't seem to work..
Here's some console action:

```
$ rails c
>> time_span = 1.month
=> 1 month
>> date = DateTime.now + time_span
=> Fri, 27 Aug 2010 20:51:18 -0500
>> time_span.class
=> Fixnum
>> time_span = '1.month'
=> "1.month"
>> date = DateTime.now + time_span
TypeError: expected numeric
    ruby/1.8/date.rb:1236:in `plus_without_duration'
    date/calculations.rb:87:in `+'
    from (irb):5
```

The idea is that I need to store 1.month as a string in the database because storing 1.month as a fixnum only stores the total number of seconds in that particular month, but I want it to be more dynamic based on the current month. I know `send` in this case isn't being used as it's documentation suggests, but I have seen it used in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
time_span = "1.month"
date = DateTime.now + eval(time_span)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `send`, you probably want `eval`... but on the other hand, you should probably avoid using `eval`.

If `time_span` is always in the form of `1.month` (ie. the magnitude and unit separated by a dot), you could parse it out as into an object call:

```
magnitude, unit = time_span.split('.')
date += magnitude.to_i.send(unit)
```

Another solution would be to save the magnitude and unit separately in the database, but then do the same thing, `send` the unit to the magnitude.

Obviously this won't work if the magnitude is not a number or the unit is not one of Rails' `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Numeric::Time` extensions.

Comment: `eval` is usually discouraged because it can be a vulnerability -- if you don't strictly control what is being evaluated, you can provide an attacker with a great way to break into your system (because eval will evaluate whatever string it's given within the context of your application)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to serialize 1.month in database.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end
```

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799